# git diff using change IDs

Tags: git, gerrit

I need to find the difference between two branches by gerrit Change IDs, not by files or commit IDs. I mean, the commits which are not in one branch.

Is there any way to get the diff by gerrit change IDs??

Answer (score 2):

Since you can only diff between commits that are actually stored in your (local) repository, you need to fetch the commits that belong to your change first, i.e. using `git review -d <id>`. Afterwards, you will have the commits in your repository at which point you can do a simple diff between those commit hashes.

Comment: so there is not way i can use change IDs to calculate diff??

Comment: You could write a script that automatically fetches the changeset and then performs a diff on it, so you don’t have to look up the commit ids manually. But no, without fetching the changes first, it’s not possible from your local machine. The Gerrit interface may provide something like that (although I only know about diffs within a single change).

Comment: yes but I know bit i dont want to use COMMIT IDs (SHA1) i want to calculate diff using GERRIT CHANGE ID.

Comment: I know. Read my answer again?